# Execute task before EntityManager is closed

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink, entitymanager

I would like to execute a task **before** the EntityManager is closed (e.g. on shutdown of the AS or undelpoying the app) and looking for a Hook or Listener or something similar.

The actual problem:
I want to save a lot of tiny data in the database with my application. To ease the load on the database I cached the data in a List and want to save all the data in an given interval.

This works great so far but in case the AS is shutting down the data will be lost. That's the reason why I want to save the data before the EntityManager is closed.

What I tried so far:
I tried to use the @PreDestroy annotation to save the data before the bean is destroyed. Unfortunately the use of the EntityManager is not working and, as I read later, not allowed in PreDestroy-methods.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@DependsOn(value = "StatisticRepository")
public class StatisticService {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(StatisticService.class.getName());

    @EJB
    private StatisticRepository repository;
    private List<Statistic> stats = new ArrayList<>();

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Saving before destroying Service.");
        for (Statistic stat : stats) {
            // ---> EntityManager in Repository already destroyed
            repository.create(stat);
        }
        stats.clear();
    }
...
}
```

.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class StatisticRepository extends BaseRepository<Statistic>{
    public StatisticRepository() {
        super(Statistic.class);
    }

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME)
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }
    ...
}
```

.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseRepository<T extends Serializable> {

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();
    private final Class<T> entityClass;

    public BaseRepository(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    public T create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
        getEntityManager().flush();
        return this.edit(entity);
    }
    ...
}
```

I get this exception on

```
Information:   Saving Statistics before destroying Service.
Warnung:   RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [{ PoolInfo : (name=java:app/pool), (applicationName=AppName) }: Es ist kein Poolmetadaten-Objekt mit dem Pool { PoolInfo : (name=java:app/pool), (applicationName=AppName) } verknüpft. Stellen Sie die Anwendung erneut bereit. ]
Warnung:   Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: { PoolInfo : (name=java:app/pool), (applicationName=AppName) }: Es ist kein Poolmetadaten-Objekt mit dem Pool { PoolInfo : (name=java:app/pool), (applicationName=AppName) } verknüpft. Stellen Sie die Anwendung erneut bereit. 
Error Code: 0
...
```

It seems the pool(which is app-scoped) is already undeployed.

Full stacktrace:
[here](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=3kMGvjge)

I create my JNDI resource and connection pool over the glassfish-resources.xml. Thus it's **not** an application-server-wide resource. Maybe that's the key to reproduce the error?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
  <!-- MySQL -->
  <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false"
                        associate-with-thread="false"
                        connection-creation-retry-attempts="0"
                        connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10"
                        connection-leak-reclaim="false"
                        connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0"
                        connection-validation-method="auto-commit"
                        datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"
                        fail-all-connections="false"
                        idle-timeout-in-seconds="170"
                        is-connection-validation-required="true"
                        is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true"
                        transaction-isolation-level="repeatable-read"
                        lazy-connection-association="false"
                        lazy-connection-enlistment="false"
                        match-connections="false"
                        max-connection-usage-count="0"
                        max-pool-size="100"
                        max-wait-time-in-millis="60000"
                        name="java:app/mysql_app_appPool"
                        non-transactional-connections="false"
                        ping="true"
                        pool-resize-quantity="2"
                        pooling="true"
                        res-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                        statement-cache-size="0"
                        statement-leak-reclaim="false"
                        statement-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0"
                        statement-timeout-in-seconds="0"
                        steady-pool-size="20"
                        validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0"
                        wrap-jdbc-objects="true">
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  </jdbc-connection-pool>
  <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="java:app/jdbc/app" object-type="user" pool-name="java:app/mysql_app_appPool"/>
```

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <!-- Persistence Unit for MySQL -->
  <persistence-unit name="com.app.web_app-webapp_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:app/jdbc/app</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="metadata-then-script"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source" value="metadata"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation-target" value="database"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Questions:
What do you think about the mechanism in general?
Does the caching make sense since JPA may handle it better on his own?
Are there any listeners or hooks?

Comment: have you tried decorating your pre-destroy method with a @Transactional annotation? Also, why would you like to perform the data caching yourself? Have you tried to configure caching options on your JPA provider?

Comment: Also, you could use a Singleton ejb bean annotatied with @Startup, however you still need to clarify if you're caching data per stateless call.

Comment: You shouldn't reinvent the wheel. You have plenty of JPA caching options by using eclipselink. Also, If you're working with high availavility requierements you should have a look at Infinispan for real life performance app data caching.

Comment: If you're concerned about losing data, you shouldn't cache writes to the database. If your application or server crashes, the data will be lost, whatever the hook you have implemented. This sounds like dangerous premature optimization to me.

Comment: Could you post your code on 'StatisticRepository'? Are you getting a NullPointerException or an entity manager exception?

Comment: I updated the question with code and exception. The point is, I will get more ore less one write-operation per request which is simply not good for the performance of the database. Note that only the writes are that expensive so the normal EclipseLink cache wouldn't help that much I think. Am I right? And I don't care if data is lost on server-crash but I don't wanna loose data if I don't need to (for example on AS restart or app redeploy). Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: Ok, let me see If I understood you use case. You intend to save your data in memory, then, once in a while (per request, per scheduled task, per server restart), you'll flush your in-memory entities into the databese. Did I understood correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I hold the data in memory and, let's say every 30mins, I want to flush that data into the database. If the system flushed the data 15mins ago and I restart the server or redeploy the app, the data currently in memory will not be flushed to the database and is lost. To prevent this I want to flush that data to the database before the system is going down (so to say out of schedule).

Comment: Ok!, could you post the full stacktrace? It's odd to me that I can't reproduce this, and it seems is a database exception rather than a JPA one.

Comment: Once this exception is solved, the rest is piece of cake. eclipselink has a batch-update property wich you should be using to improve batch insert operations. something really useful for tasks like for(YourEntitiy ent : listOfEntities){em.persist(ent);}

Comment: That's true...I just wanted to test it this way and I failed ;)

Comment: I added a link to the full stacktrace and the glassfish-resources.xml content to create an app-scoped connection pool and JNDI resource.

Comment: Are you certain the pool has beeen deployed correctly? Can you ping the database from the admin screen? Also, the persistence.xml could be useful, just in case something is missing.

Comment: The connection to the database is working correctly. Everything I requested directly before the whole problem is delivered successfully.

Comment: just in case, remove the "stats.clear();" line. That method might be faster than the em.persist operations, therefore invalidating the entities (ready to be garbage collected).

Comment: Uh, really good idea, unfortunately nothing changed :/

Comment: Have you tried resizing the pool size? I don't dont know how many instances you're trying to persist. 512 connections and 8 to 64 resize values should do the trick.

Comment: persist-flush-merge operations are really expensive. Avoid them only if you dont need any database generated ID or else. Use em.persist alone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56846/discussion-between-yser-and-ra2085).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have plenty of caching options on eclipselink. Have a look [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/Configuring).

Also, for real life performance, I strongly recommend to use Infinspan. Have a look [here](http://infinispan.org/documentation/).

If your use case is really simple, then a `@Singleton` ejb bean annotated with `@Startup` should do the trick. Like this:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class StartupShutdownBean {

    @PostConstruct
    private void startup() {
        // your startup code here
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void shutdown() {
        // your shutdown code here
    }

}
```

You shouldn't have any problem injecting an `EntityManager` on this bean. Most likely, you cant use an entity manager in your bean because the transaction ends before you can perform a "cache update".

EDIT:

It seems the app configured resources are being deleted by the AS before your `@PreDestroy` call, therefore you shoud use the `preserveAppScopedResources=true` parameter in your asadmin deploy or redeploy commands in order to keep the pool alive during those operations.

Some documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/giydj.html).

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't worked for me. I tested it with '@DependsOn' too. BTW all other operations with the bean containing the entitymanager are working just fine. It seems the connection pool(which is app-scoped) for the database is already closed on '@PreDestroy'.